# ASP.NET - Redirect to Error Page if Roles Authorization Fails

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I am using MVC 3 with Forms Authentication. On my controller or methods, I am doing the following:

```
[Authorize (Roles = "developer")]
```

In this situation, I want to check if the user is logged in and if not, return them to the login page. However, if the 'IsInRole' check for that user returns false, I want them to go to a different view that says something like 'Not authorized'.

What is the best way to accomplish something like this? I was hoping to avoid creating a new Authorization attribute so I didn't have to refactor every Authorize attribute in my entire application, but if that is what is required, I will go that route.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A custom authorize attribute overriding the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method could do the job:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else if (!this.Roles.Split(',').Any(filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole))
        {
            // The user is not in any of the listed roles => 
            // show the unauthorized view
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml"
            };
        }
        else
        { 
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[MyAuthorize(Roles = "developer")]
public ActionResult Develop()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where do you put this custom implementation?

Comment: @darin-dimitrov Where should we keep the custom implementations, is there a convention/recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with custom error page for 401 status codes.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733064/how-do-i-display-custom-error-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-3/7368489#7368489) for implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this.Because if you dont have authority it comes method.
Authorization control is not necessary

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml",
            };
        }
    }
```