# Redirect to Error Page instead of Login Page for false AuthorizationManager response in ASP .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

We implemented a custom AuthorizationManager. Instead of putting the logic in the code, we designed a stored procedure that checks the user role against a table with controllers and action and returns 0 or 1 for access. The AuthorizationManager then process the result and returns true or false. All that works well but when it returns false, it automatically redirects to the login page and asks the user to login even after the user has been authenticated. Is it possible to override this behavior and redirects to the error page with a ViewBag containing the error message. I have looked online and i can't see to find anything.

```
 public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager

{
    private testDbContext db = new testDbContext();
    public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString();

        var AuthoriseYN = db.Database.SqlQuery<AuthoriseViewModel>("EXEC spControllerActionRole @Controller, @Action, @Username",
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Controller", resrce.Value),
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Action", action.Value),
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("Username", username)
        ).ToList();
        bool authorise = AuthoriseYN[0].Authorise;
            if (authorise == true)
        {
            return true;
        }



        return false
```

Comment: Here you go, I believe this post will give you what you need (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447705/asp-net-redirect-to-error-page-if-roles-authorization-fails)

Comment: @RyanWilson sorry but i still don't get it.