# Where and how to define <customErrors mode=”on”> for my asp.net MVC 3 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, custom-errors

I want to set the custome error to be true to prevent users from viewing detailed info about my application. But I cannot find where I should write this `<customErrors mode="on">`; should it be in the web.config or in the web, debug.config or else where?

BR

Answer (score 95):

From my experience, we should turn custom error to On in release mode and turn it off in debug. To automatically do this, we can use web.config transformation like the following example.

**Web.Debug.config**

This setting will allow web server to display ASP.NET yellow page that contain useful error information.

```
<customErrors mode="Off" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

**Web.Release.config**

In the other hand, we don't want user to know technical error. We should use custom error page instead of ASP.NET yellow page.

```
<customErrors mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

Comment: Why not `RemoteOnly`? Then you won't have to use XML transformation and developers can see the errors when viewing the site on the webserver.

Comment: Sometimes it's just not convenient to view the site from the web server? (Not that your point doesn't have merit..)

Comment: It should perhaps be pointed out that `<customErrors` node needs to exist in some form in the web config, in order to be `xdt:Transform="Replace"`d - If there is no `<customErrors` node in the web.config, then adding these lines to web.Release.config will not cause the node to be added. Use ``xdt:Transform="Insert"`` if the web.config has no `<customErrors` node at all and you want the transformation to add it

Answer (score 7):

This will depend, but normally should be in the Web.config file.

The Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config (and other configuration variations) are used for when you deploy your application. When you perform a publish operation, the transform is applied to your Web.config file during deployment, which means you can have specific configuration settings applied for debug, release, and other configurations that you have set up.

If you don't normally perform a publish operation during development, then you will need to apply this setting to the Web.config file in order for it to take affect.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx for more details about transforming the Web.config file.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx for an example of adding the customErrors element to the Web.config file.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a great video on Channel 9 about deployment and how to effectively use the debug and release versions of the web.config. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/FT14

Comment: i define  <customErrors mode="on" /> in the web.config before closing the </configuration> tag as follow:- </system.webServer>
  <customErrors mode="on" />
</configuration>
but if an error occur then a full error message (not custom error)will be displayed...!!!

Comment: Place the <customErrors> element under the <system.web> tag. You would also need to specify the defaultRedirect, either to a controller action, or preferably a static html file. Alternatively, many people have kept custom errors off, and then handled the routing in the application error handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733064/how-do-i-display-custom-error-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-3 for details.

Comment: thanks for ur reply; i insert the <customErros> under the <system.web> as in ;   <system.web> <customErrors mode= "On" > </customErrors>. but still an detailed error will be displayed.

Comment: Have you set the defaultRedirect attribute to point to an action or a static html file? See the link I put in the comment for details.

Answer (score 5):

Put in  in Web.config and create an error page for redirect.
In MVC, you have HandleErrorAttribute, mark it on class to handler unexpected error, logged it and throw error page. Custom Error is default page for specific error with known status code.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="/PageNotFound?" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```