# An application error occurred on the server ASP.net Selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have made an application using selenium on asp.net that automates to facebook.com and login. My website is running on visual studio but after uploading to my hosing i am getting this error. I am new on asp.net , please help me!

[image]

Comment: You'll need to try harder a bit - first step is getting relevant log why the error is happening in the first place - check out event viewer on machine where you run the application or turn on full errors - see for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286113/where-and-how-to-define-customerrors-mode-on-for-my-asp-net-mvc-3-web-applic

Comment: someone said to me it is not possible to run selenium on asp.net in live websites, it runs only test project on visual studio ! Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines,  please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. The  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

More info: [Asp.net - <customErrors mode="Off"/> error when trying to access working webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363941/asp-net-customerrors-mode-off-error-when-trying-to-access-working-webpage)