# How can I map directly from my Application-specific exceptions to Http Exceptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter, custom-error-pages, handleerror

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 application. In the so-called "Business Layer" of our App, we have made a decision to **always throw some specific types of exceptions** depending on the situation. We have an Exception type hierarchy when a user tries supposed to do something he is not authorized, and special exceptions when the application cannot find a given item (by Id or name or whatever).

This looks like this in our C# Code :

```
// ... more stuff
public Something GetSomething(int id, User currentUser){
    var theSomething = SomethingRepository.Get(id);
    if(theSomething == null){
        throw new SomethingNotFoundException(id, "more details");
    }

    if(!PermissionService.CanLoadSomething(currentUser)){
        throw new NotAuthorizedException("You shall not pass");
    }

    // the rest of the method etc etc
    // ...
}
```

... where `SomethingNotFoundException` and `NotAuthorizedException` are custom `Exception`s .

There is somehow a **direct mapping** between this kind of exceptions and the Http Status Code (404 Not Found / 403 Forbidden), and we would like our Controller methods to handle those errors accordingly (showing the 404/403 CustomError pages and things like that). Now, what we want is to avoid having to do this in our controller actions :

```
public ViewResult Get(int id){
    try{
        var theSomething = MyService.GetSomething(id, theUser);
    }
    catch(SomethingNotFoundException ex){
        throw new HttpException(404, ex);
    }
    catch(NotAuthorizedExceptionex){
        throw new HttpException(403, ex);
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure there must be a way to use either a custom HandleErrorAttribute or a custom ActionFilterAttribute and register it in the Global.asax, but I cannot figure out how to have it working .

**Attempt 1 : HandleErrorAttribute**

I first tried making a subclass of HandleErrorAttribute, overriding the `OnException` method as such :

```
public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }

    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
    // Map some of the Business Exception to correspounding HttpExceptions !
    if (exception is ObjectNotFoundException)
    {
        // consider it as a NotFoundException !
        exception = new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not found", exception);
        filterContext.Exception = exception;

    }
    else if (exception is NotAuthorizedException)
    {
        // consider it as a ForbiddenException 
        exception = new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden", exception);
        filterContext.Exception = exception;
    }

    base.OnException(filterContext);

}
```

... and adding it to the `GlobalFilterCollection` in Global.asax ... but it is still handled as if it were the usual 500 error, instead of showing the 404/403 custom error pages...

**Attempt 2 : ActionFilterAttribute**

I also tried making it an `ActionFilterAttribute` and overriding the `OnActionExecuted` method like this :

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
    }
    Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
    if(exception!=null)
    {
        // Map some of the Business Exception to correspounding HttpExceptions !
        if (exception is ObjectNotFoundException)
        {
            // consider it as a NotFoundException !
            var wrappingException = new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Not found", exception);
            exception = wrappingException;
            filterContext.Exception = exception;
        }
        else if (exception is NotAuthorizedException)
        {
            // consider it as a ForbiddenException 
            var wrappingException = new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden", exception);
            exception = wrappingException;
            filterContext.Exception = exception;
        }
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

... but still, I get the 500 error page instead of 404 or 403 ...

**Am I doing something wrong ? Is there possibly a better way ?**

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few options.

You probably want :[This guys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc) solution

You can do it like this [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733064/how-do-i-display-custom-error-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-3).

You could have a base Controller class that all your classes inherit from and use the below method.  This is how my last company addressed the issue.

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
       Console.WriteLine(filterContext.Exception.ToString());
}
```