# ASP.NET MVC, CustomErrors & ResponseRewrite

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-errors

I have an MVC website (v5, though I don't think it's related) where I have intentionally introduced an error upon when attempting to establish a database connection (wrong server IP in the connection string). When the user hits the HomeController one dependencies for the constructor is a UserRepository (to get the current user profile data) which depends on a database connection/session to be available. When it's not, the Dependency Resolver can't inject the UserRepository and when that happens it causes an error (as it does with any dependency of any controller), and I get a generic "No parameterless constructor defined for this object". Which is pretty useless.

So I'm trying to use a custom error page to retrieve the inner exception and display it in a friendly manner. (Because this error is happening when trying to acquire the HomeController, it never actually reaches the HandleErrorAttribute, hence the relying on CustomErrors).

So I have an ErrorsController with a series of actions...

**Snippet from ErrorsComtroller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View("Error_500");
}

public ActionResult NotFound()
{
    return View("Error_404");
}
```

**Snippet from web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errors/notfound" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/errors/error" />
</customErrors>
```

The Error_500 page is pretty basic, it has a model type of `HandleErrorInfo`, but if it's not present it checks for Exception details using `Server.GetLastError()`. Problem is, `GetLastError()` is always null, and I get my custom error page but no additional details beyond my generic feedback of "An unexpected error has occured". After doing some digging I found that the method doesn't work after a redirect, which is the default way the CustomErrors functions. So I changed the web.config to use this line instead...

**Snippet from web.config**

This way it won't cause a redirect and the `GetLastError()` should have my exception details about the database connection problem. Thing is, now I get the default ASP.NET error page with this message.

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally,
>   another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for
>   the first exception. The request has been terminated.

So I did some more digging using intellitrace, and I see the exception about the database connection. A little farther down I see the error about not having a parameterless constructor on HomeController and then one about encountering an error trying to create the controller of type 'HomeController'. But then I see one that says

> Error executing child request for /errors/error

So I navigated directly to that path and the page works fine. But when it's used in customerrors WITH the `ResponseRewrite` for the redirectmode, it errors out. I put a break line on the first (and only) line of the `ErrorsController.Error()` action, but it never gets hit. If I substitute the redirect path in the custom errors to a static file it works, but if I change it back to the `~/errors/error` it fails again.

Is there a issue when using MVC actions as url's for the CustomErrors when `ResponseRewrite` is specified?

Answer (score 4):

"This happens because "ResponseRewrite" mode uses Server.Transfer under the covers, which looks for a file on the file system. As a result you need to change the redirect path to a static file, for example to an .aspx or .html file:"

`<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx"/>`

See: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

"Apparently, Server.Transfer is not compatible with MVC routes, therefore, if your error page is served by a controller action, Server.Transfer is going to look for /Error/Whatever, not find it on the file system, and return a generic 404 error page!"

See: [CustomErrors does not work when setting redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781861/customerrors-does-not-work-when-setting-redirectmode-responserewrite)

In other words, you cannot use ResponseRewrite with views.

This is a well known issue that has been problematic for developers because it does not afford itself to either an easy or elegant solution. Bottom line, MVC does not play nice when using custom views for exception handling and customer user-friendly pages for HTTP errors. The stock error.cshtml file (i.e., a View) in the Views\Shared folder is a great thing to have because it maintains the layout of the web page and provides exception errors. But, when you get HTTP errors then you need to create a view to handle the status code errors (e.g., 404, 500, etc.). Note: if you go the route of sending HTTP errors to a view then the URL line will contain non-ideal info (see weblinks below for further explanation).

You could route HTTP errors to the Error view, but I don't recommend it because the Error view should be for application errors (i..e, exceptions) whereas a separate custom user-friendly page should be created for generic HTTP errors. The difference is that the former is an application problem that the site developer needs to look at whereas the latter is a user error (or at least should be) that does not require the developer to look at it (just my 2 cents).

An alternative is to bypass the views and use custom user-friendly pages for both application exceptions and HTTP errors. But, beware of two problems:

1.) The wrong status code is returned (usually 200), which can be a problem because it will be picked up and indexed by search engines (you do not want this!)

2.) The URL specifies a non-sensical URL in the web browser

These can be handled easy enough. See the following link (go down to the section **customErrors in web.config**): https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

Below are other weblinks that I also found useful:

http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-mvc-custom-error-pages

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.aspx

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNEjXCSnw6w

[How do I display custom error pages in Asp.Net Mvc 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733064/how-do-i-display-custom-error-pages-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

The last one appears to be yet another alternative: a custom hack to get around the problem of not being able to couple views with ResponseRewrite. This works by completely bypassing CustomErrors (i.e., CustomErrors mode="Off"). I have not yet tried this yet, but I am looking into it.

Final thought, keep an eye on all site status codes when either error or exception codes are thrown - make sure there are no 200 (i.e., OK) codes.