# 404 Custom Error Page Mvc3 working only with non-existing routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages, httpexception

After browsing 100 of link for this topic I couldnt find solution to my problem. I am handling 404 custom error page manually like below

My below solution work when I type any wrong url in address bar and shows 404 error page rightly. But when I type `http://localhost:57101/p/any` or `http://localhost:57101/p/123`
it shows webpage not available. for first one its the error of parameter id cannot contain null entry. Second one is the products id which is deleted so product is null, So I am throwing manual exceptions there.

My web.config setting is

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
    </customErrors>
```

My code to handle 404 error

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //LogException(Server.GetLastError());

            try
            {
                var exception = Server.GetLastError();
                LogException(exception);
                var httpException = exception as HttpException;
                Response.Clear();
                Server.ClearError();
                var routeData = new RouteData();
                routeData.Values["controller"] = "Errors";
                routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
                routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                if (httpException != null)
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                    switch (Response.StatusCode)
                    {
                        case 403:
                            routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                            break;
                        case 404:
                            routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.StatusCode = 404;
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                }

                IController errorsController = new Nop.Web.Controllers.ErrorsController();
                var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
                errorsController.Execute(rc);
            }
            catch { }

            #endregion
            //log error

        }
```

Above code works when I try to browse any non existent route.
But when I throw exception as below

My Errors controller is

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Errors/

        public ActionResult General(Exception exception)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Http404()
        {
            //return Content("Not found", "text/plain");
            Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Http403()
        {
            Response.ContentType = "text/html";
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return View();
        }
    }


public ActionResult Product(int productId)  
        {

            var product = _productService.GetProductById(productId);


            if(product==null)
                throw new HttpException(404, "Product does not exists");

          }
```

It shows "This webpage is not available".

Also I want to keep url as it is just like `stackoverflow` does it.

Any help regarding this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203918/catch-404-error-in-mvc4

Comment: Tries this but same result works with non existent routes but not with throwing exceptions manually

Comment: Nobody encountered same issue as mine?

Comment: No we can remove that because I am setting that in Application_Error itself

Comment: How/when does your else condition hit in Application_Error?

Comment: When exception isnt http exception, e.g string is passed as param to product action when it requires ineteger